# target images inside a div by it's name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a button that resizes down images inside it's div,

```
function aumenta(){
    var mydiv = $('div[name|="visualizacoes"]');
    var curr_width = parseInt(mydiv.style.width);
    var curr_height = parseInt(mydiv.style.height);

    if (curr_width < 4123) {            
        mydiv.style.width = (curr_width + 412) +"px";
        mydiv.style.height = (curr_height + 466) +"px";
    }
    }
```

it's not working, maybe this is not the way to get the element's name?
My problem is that i have several div's hidden that show up on menu click,
I'm trying to get all of them to resize even if they're hidden, that's why im targeting it's name, could be the class as well!! Please help! Thanks

Comment: Show us your markup, ideally a small-but-representative sample.

Comment: A `div` shouldn't *have* a `name` attribute (those are reserved for `input` elements and, historically, `a` elements). They can have an `id` or `class` though, and custom `data-*` attributes.

Comment: The `style` object resides on HTMLElement objects, but you're calling it on a jQuery object (assuming the `$` relates to jQuery and not some other library). Either retrieve the native element from the jQuery stack before doing this (`mydiv[0]` or `mydiv.get(0)`) or use jQuery's own means of deciphering width/height (e.g. `.width()` or `.css('width')`).

Answer (score 0):

Create a class, then make all the images a member of that class.

If you do this, you can then use the jQuery "each()" method to iterate through each element, and manipulate them in a loop...

```
$('.<classname>').each(function(e){
    var element = $(this);
    var currWidth = element.width();
    var currHeight = element.height();

    if( currWidth < 4123 ){
        element.width( currWidth + 412 );
        element.height( currHeight + 412 );
    }
});
```

In the above I've also used the jQuery width() and height() methods to get *and* set the elements height and width.